# Mouse wheel not working on 22.04

Tags: scrolling, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

My logitech M330 mouse (connected using usb dongle) is working fine but the scroll wheel isn't...

I am on Ubuntu 22.04

Any idea ?
Thanks !
Vincent

Comment: If it's cordless, I'd likely check your battery, but if it's not battery; I'd likely boot another OS & see if it performs the same there (eg. does the mouse have a hardware issue).  If your system isn't dual boot; I'd just use a *live* OS, and I'd opt for a very different *software stack* to what you're currently using (ie. not 22.04, not a non-Ubuntu, or very different Ubuntu product/release).. but that's just my ideas/2c.\

Comment: My "*not a non-Ubuntu*" wasn't what I'd intended sorry.  What I meant was for the *live* I'd not use 22.04 probably, and opt personally for a non-Ubuntu if available/handy, or if Ubuntu a very different Ubuntu product/release (or at minimum a different kernel stack to what you're using).  (*Easy for me as I've a load of thumb-drives here with many Ubuntu products, plus a handful of non-Ubuntu's too*)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my mouse is fine, it works well with other OSs

Comment: @VinzM, have you fixed it? Could you share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, I just umnplugged the mouse, then plugged it back in, and it worked...